# Can a proto3 scalar field be changed to optional without breaking wire compatibility?

Tags: compatibility, backwards-compatibility, grpc-java, proto3

Can I change a scalar field in proto3 to optional, *e.g.*

```
message UpdateAccountRequest {
  string name = 1;
  string country = 2;
}
```

to

```
message UpdateAccountRequest {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional string country = 2;
}
```

without breaking anything? That is, without affecting clients who are currently always setting those fields.